Refetching queries in apollo-client regardless of the input parameters
I am having an issue with refetching queries in apollo-client after mutation. Hope someone can help.
My graphql schema has one query and one mutation:
type Query {
  alerts(filter: AlertFilter!): AlertsResponse!
}

type Mutation {
  closeAlert(input: CloseAlertRequest!): CloseAlertResponse!
}

The alerts query accepts an AlertFilter with status = OPEN or CLOSED. It returns a list of alerts along with open & closed alert counts.
The closeAlert mutation closes the specified alert.
What I am trying to do is to refetch the alerts query whenever the closeAlert mutation is called. This is to make sure that I have the latest list of alerts + the latest open/close counts.
Here's how I have coded my closeAlert mutation. It is trying to refetch the alertsPage query after the mutation.
export function useCloseAlert() {
  return useMutation(closeAlertDocument, {
    refetchQueries: ['alertsPage'],
  });
}

My alertsPage query is coded like this:
const alertsPageDocument = graphql(/* GraphQL */ `
  query alertsPage($filter: AlertFilter!) {
    alerts(filter: $filter) {
      alerts {
        id
        ...AlertItem
      }
      counts {
        status
        count
        ...AlertCountItem
      }
    }
  }
`);

However, looking at the Apollo Client DevTools extension, I see that there are two distinct alertsPage queries in the cache (see screenshot below): one for filter status="OPEN" and another for filter status="Closed". The mutation only refetches the query for filter status="OPEN" - I can see the open count go down and closed count go up. However the query for filter status="CLOSED" is not refetched and the counts don't change at all.
Question: How can I tell Apollo client to refetch all alertsPage queries, regardless of the input values?


Answering my own question...
In order to refetch both queries (for status=OPEN and status=CLOSED), I had to change refetchQueries as follows:
export function useCloseAlert() {
  return useMutation(closeAlertDocument, {
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: AlertsPageDocument,
        variables: {
          filter: { status: 'OPEN' },
        },
      },
      {
        query: AlertsPageDocument,
        variables: {
          filter: { status: 'CLOSED' },
        },
      },
    ],
  });
}


